# How to focus a currently opened Document in JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, awt

I want to set the focus on the current opened Document. I click on the Create Menu item for multiple times; it opens multiple Documents, but the focus is on the first document only. I want the focus to be on the newly opened Document.

My code:

```
public class CreateDocs extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    int i=0;
    JTextPane textPane;
    public CreateDocs() {
        initComponents();
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        tabbedPane = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
        menuBar = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
        jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        create = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jMenu1.setText("File");

        create.setText("Create");
        create.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                createActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jMenu1.add(create);

        menuBar.add(jMenu1);

        setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 410, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(tabbedPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 410, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 279, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(tabbedPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 279, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    private void createActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
       final JInternalFrame internalFrame = new JInternalFrame("");
        i++;
        internalFrame.setName("Document"+i);
        internalFrame.setClosable(true);
        internalFrame.setAutoscrolls(true);
        textPane=new JTextPane();
        textPane.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Miriam Fixed", 0, 14));
        internalFrame.add(textPane);
        tabbedPane.add(internalFrame);
        internalFrame.setFocusable(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CreateDocs.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CreateDocs.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CreateDocs.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CreateDocs.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new CreateDocs().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem create;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
    private javax.swing.JMenuBar menuBar;
    private javax.swing.JTabbedPane tabbedPane;
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `requestFocus()`?

Comment: Yes,I had tried that not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you create `JInternalFrame` and add it to `JTabbedPane`.

Use `JDesktopPane` and add the `JInternalFrame`  OR use just `JPanel` to add it in the `JTabbedPane`.

then use `tabbedPane.setSelectedIndex()` and then if necessary call `requestFocus()` on the `JTextPane` in the tab.

Comment: In My project need JInternalFrame with JTabbedPane.Please give suggestions with respect to the above.

Comment: Why do you need JInternalFrame with JTabbedPane?

Comment: For creating multiple documents and I wrote more code with respect to internalframe and tabbedpane.Not possible to change the code.